# setting up pycurl for embedded ARM

Tags: python, embedded, curl, petalinux

I am working on a linux x86_64 machine, and I am trying to set up pycurl for an embedded ARM processor running petalinux. I need pycurl library before building the embedded linux image. I have cross-compiled libcurl, and I've been trying to use curl-config from that libcurl to build pycurl.

```
python setup.py build --curl-config=/path/to/crossedcompiled/curl-config
```

However, the output I'm seeing in the build folder is still produced by x86_64-gcc. Has anyone done something similar?